# What is the maximum possible value for an angle where the sum of its supplementary and complementary angles is a positive counting number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, algebraic-geometry, optimization

I'm trying to calculate the measure of the optimised angle in degrees.

I began by calculating the sum of the comp. and supp. angles:

$(x-90)+(180-x)>0$

And got

$90>0$

I tried plugging in values greater than 90, and got positive angles. Guidance on problems with conditions is appreciated, as I find that I need to work more on them.

Comment: do you only want angles smaller than $360°$?

Comment: Yes I'm looking for angles that are within that range, although I doubt that the angle would exceed 180.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The complement of an angle $\theta°$ measures $(90-\theta)°$.

**The whole solution**:
The revised inequality becomes $$(90-\theta)° + (180-\theta)° > 0°$$
$$\implies \theta°<135°$$

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted to look for solutions within a narrower range where more conditions apply? For example, an added requirement to the question of an angle that was a multiple of 5 or the least common multiple of, say, x and y?

Comment: @trevor1080 then you find the largest number smaller than 135 that satisfies your extra conditions